# How to compose Interfaces without using a sub-Interface or an explicit class

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to figure out a straightforward way to compose Interfaces without creating a new sub-Interface as the Interfaces have a multi-dimensional relationship.

```
interface IAnimal {}

interface ISwimmingAnimal : IAnimal {}

interface IVertebrate : IAnimal {}

interface IMammal : IVertebrate
{
    IMammal Process();
}

interface IInvertebrate : IAnimal {}

interface IMollusc : IInvertebrate
{
    IMollusc Process(object data);
}
```

Thus some concrete classes would be

```
class Vertebrate : IVertebrate {}

class SwimmingInvertebrate : ISwimmingAnimal, IInvertebrate {}

class SwimmingMammal : ISwimmingAnimal, IMammal
{
    IMammal Process();
}
```

without needing a composition Interface, such as `ISwimmingAnimalInvertebrate` or `ISwimmingAnimalMammal`.

All well and good until I need to use a class/Interface that will contain instances of some compostioned types (What I want in theory):

```
interface IAnimalsCollection
{
    IEnumerable<IAnimal> Items { get; } //Aggregate collection of Vertebrate and Invertebrates
    {IAnimal, IVertebrate} Vertebrate { get; }
    IEnumerable<{IAnimal, IInvertebrate}> Invertebrates { get; }

    void UpdateVertebrate({IAnimal, IVertebrate} vertebrate);
    void UpdateInvertebrate({IAnimal, IInvertebrate} invertebrate, int index);
}

class SwimmingAnimalsCollection : IAnimalsCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<ISwimmingAnimal> Items { get; } //Aggregate collection of Vertebrate and Invertebrates
    public {ISwimmingAnimal, IMammal} Vertebrate { get; }
    public IEnumerable<{ISwimmingAnimal, IMollusc}> Invertebrates { get; }

    public void UpdateVertebrate({ISwimmingAnimal, IMammal} vertebrate);
    public void UpdateInvertebrate({ISwimmingAnimal, IMollusc} invertebrate, int index);
}
```

I've tried this

```
interface IAnimalsCollection<TAnimal, TVertebrate, TInvertebrate>
    where TAnimal : IAnimal
    where TVertebrate : TAnimal, IVertebrate
    where TInvertebrate : TAnimal, IInvertebrate
{
    IEnumerable<IAnimal> Items { get; } //Aggregate collection of Vertebrate and Invertebrates
    {IAnimal, IVertebrate} Vertebrate { get; }
    IEnumerable<{IAnimal, IInvertebrate}> Invertebrates { get; }

    void UpdateVertebrate(TVertebrate vertebrate);
    void UpdateInvertebrate(TInvertebrate invertebrate, int index);
}

class SwimmingAnimalsCollection<TAnimal, TVertebrate, TInvertebrate> : AnimalsCollection<TAnimal, TVertebrate, TInvertebrate>
    where TAnimal : ISwimmingAnimal
    where TVertebrate : TAnimal, IMammal
    where TInvertebrate : TAnimal, IMollusc
{
    public IEnumerable<TAnimal> Items { get; } //Aggregate collection of Vertebrate and Invertebrates
    public TVertebrate Vertebrate { get; }
    public IEnumerable<TInvertebrate> Invertebrates { get; }

    public void UpdateVertebrate(TVertebrate vertebrate) {}
    public void UpdateInvertebrate(TInvertebrate invertebrate, int index) {}
}
```

Except I can't find a way to instantiate `SwimmingAnimalsCollection` with just Interfaces, as that was the problem I was trying to solve in the first place, nor can I use the class implementations due to `IMammal` and `IMollusc` potentially returning entirely different classes.
In fact, in the actual implementation, there are pairs of classes that are `UnProcessedX` that will return a `ProcessedX` class, which will just return itself if you attempt to process it further.

Since I would like to do

```
collection.UpdateVertebrate((TVertebrate)collection.Vertebrate.Process())
```

and a `ProcessedVertebrate` is not an `UnProssesedVertebrate`.

I see roughly three ways to solve this:

- I could break down and create compositional Interfaces, killing any
  simple dependency injection.
- I could create dummy abstract base classes (and hope nothing needs a
  deep inheritance chain), killing any possibility of dependency
  injection.
- Or I could beat the C# compiler with a magic wand until it relents
  and allows in-place interface composition.

Comment: The keyword is already in your question. Composition. Not inheritance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @CodeCaster Then I'm not sure I've explained myself correctly.  I don't want a class that can do A, B, and C, I want a class that can hold instances of {IA, IB} and {IA IC} without defining IAB and IAC intermediate Interfaces.

Comment: But all `IB` and `IC` in your example are `IA`, why would you need to constraint to both?

Comment: @InBetween Because I want to use the methods/properties/whatever that IB and IC would expose.

Comment: And actually, it's a class (as the example shows) that holds {IA Ia}, {Ia Ib}, and {Ia Ic}.  I.E. I want the other two types to ALSO be convertible not to just IA (their base interface), but also Ia, a derived interface unrelated to themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you can get to what you want is the following set up:

```
public interface IAnimal { }
public interface IVertebrate<out TAnimal>: IAnimal where TAnimal : IAnimal { }
public interface IInvertebrate<out TAnimal>: IAnimal where TAnimal : IAnimal { }
public interface ISwimmingAnimal : IAnimal { }
public interface ISwimmingVertebrate : IVertebrate<ISwimmingAnimal> { }
public interface ISwimmingInvertebrate : IInvertebrate<ISwimmingAnimal> { }
```

Do notice that you are still creating a dependeny between interfaces. Now your collection would look like this:

```
public interface IAnimalsCollection<TAnimal, TVertebrate, TInvertebrate>
    where TAnimal: IAnimal
    where TVertebrate: IVertebrate<TAnimal>
    where TInvertebrate: IInvertebrate<TAnimal>
{
    IEnumerable<IAnimal> Animals { get; }
    IEnumerable<TVertebrate> Vertebrates { get; }
    IEnumerable<TInvertebrate> Invertebrates { get; }
    ....
}

public class AnimalsCollection<TAnimal, TVertebrate, TInvertebrate> : IAnimalsCollection<TAnimal, TVertebrate, TInvertebrate>
    where TAnimal : IAnimal
    where TVertebrate : IVertebrate<TAnimal>
    where TInvertebrate : IInvertebrate<TAnimal>
{
    public AnimalsCollection(IEnumerable<TVertebrate> vertebrates, IEnumerable<TInvertebrate> invertebrates)
    {
        Vertebrates = vertebrates;
        Invertebrates = invertebrates;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IAnimal> Animals => Vertebrates.Cast<IAnimal>().Concat(Invertebrates.Cast<IAnimal>());     
    public IEnumerable<TInvertebrate> Invertebrates { get; }
    public IEnumerable<TVertebrate> Vertebrates { get; }
}
```

Some concrete types:

```
public abstract class SwimmingAnimal: ISwimmingAnimal { }
public class JellyFish: IInvertebrate<SwimmingAnimal> { }
public class Fish: IVertebrate<SwimmingAnimal> { }
```

And now you can instantiate a concrete collection only using interfaces:

```
var swimmingCollection = new AnimalsCollection<ISwimmingAnimal, IVertebrate<ISwimmingAnimal>, IInvertebrate<ISwimmingAnimal>>(Enumerable.Empty<Fish>(), Enumerable.Empty<JellyFish>());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an getting an invalid cast exception when accessing Animals with a non-empty collection (Unable to cast object of type 'Fish' to type 'ISwimmingAnimal'.) .  And I've been trying out a merger of your suggested code and mine (where TVertebrate : TAnimal, IVertebrate<TAnimal>).  Either way, it's what I've been trying to avoid - creating intermediate composition Interfaces.

Comment: @Tory woops, made a mistake. `Animals` must return an `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`, it doesn't make sense to return an `IEnumerable<TAnimal>` becuase you cant make an interface extend a generic type; `IVertebrate` and `IInvertebrate` must implement `IAnimal`. Fixed code.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it (and is still allowable by my requirements).  And it made the code closer to my "merged" version - but oh so much simpler.  I've already checked and extending it with, say, `IMammal<out TAnimal> : IVertebrate<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal` still works with `var animals = new AnimalsCollection<ISwimmingAnimal, IMammal<ISwimmingAnimal>, IInvertebrate<ISwimmingAnimal>>(...)`.

Comment: I'll wait a day to accept the answer on the off chance that someone catches something we missed or a gotcha.  Thank you.  It's not what I wanted (otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question), but it's not as bad as I was afraid it would end up being.